# Word for someone who goes in a specific direction

Tags: single-word-requests

What is the word for someone who  follows specific instructions or does what he is told? And is there a word for the person who makes someone like this? The maker could be a tyrant or some sort of instructor.

Comment: as far as a word for someone who makes someone like this- do you mean that person's biological parents, or some sort of tyrant or authoritarian?

Comment: #1: obedient, docile, tractable, submissive, deferential, governable, loyal, subservient, compliant, obliging...  #2 manipulative, tyrannical, authoritarian, domineering, bossy, controlling, overbearing... there.  My thesaurus exercise for the day.

Comment: @WillHunting- Added some more details.

Comment: Colloquially, that person is your *bitch*.

Comment: @Robusto: That one always strikes me as a sexist black American term. I know it's often used of a male, but I've hardly ever come across it used *by a female of her male bitch*. I don't know if it's just a UK term, but I much prefer *dogsbody* (everyone wants one, but only the lucky few have them).

Comment: @Fumble: We have no dogsbodies in the U.S., and I doubt Americans who haven't read British fiction would even know what that term means. It's marginally sexist, but even (younger) American women use it casually these days: "Take that, bitches!" Although it means "subordinate female" it is fast losing the strict application of that meaning, and is used as an insulting term for anyone who has been bested or dominated.

Comment: @Robusto: Intriguing. NGrams confirms it's very much a Briticism. I'd never thought about the etymology of *dogsbody* before, but a quick Google just tells me it was originally naval slang for pease-pudding. I've no idea how it came to mean a minion, but I think we should be told...

Comment: @FumbleFingers telling Americans that 'dogsbody' means 'pease-pudding' is hilarious; at least to American ears both phrases are entirely opaque.

Comment: @Robusto is right, the term 'x's bitch' is in widespread use in the US with this meaning. It's not polite, but it's not necessarily sexist in usage; nor associated any more with AAVE. Caveat: '_my/your/his/her_ bitch' is entirely different than '_a_ bitch', which is still derogatory and sexist.

Comment: @Mark Beadles: Yeah, I think American society collectively is more "sensitive" to various racist/sexist terms than Brits. I've no idea if the actual *prejudices* involved are more common "per captita" in either nation, but numerically speaking there are bound to be more bigots in the US because it's so much bigger. I don't think most Brits perceive things like *"Aw, quit bitching, man!"* as sexist, because it's just a word there. But *"She's my bitch"* is a whole 'nother ballgame, which I and many other Brits would find quite offensive.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: Not to put too fine a point on it, but are you at once saying that American society is "more 'sensitive'" and less sensitive ("which I and many other Brits would find quite offensive")? What do Brits think when Elton John sings "the bitch is back," I wonder?

Comment: @Robusto: Badly phrased. I meant that collectively US society seems more likely to decry certain *words* in any/all contexts. UK society seems to be more relaxed about the words themselves; it's usage in context that can cause uproar. But of course, I hear more about public outcry over inappropriate language in the US if it's considered "interesting" to UK media (often, if reactions aren't similar to what we'd expect in the UK), so I may get a distorted impression. Outcry over *niggardly*, for example, may be an over-reported distortion of prevalent attitudes in the US.

Comment: why the down vote here? And I also see two close requests?!

Comment: Regarding the first part of your question...

Looking for a noun? [toady](http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/toady?s=t)

Looking for an adjective? [obsequious](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/obsequious)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the obedient one, consider adjective *[docile](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/docile)* ("Yielding to control or supervision, direction, or management.  Ready to accept instruction or direction") or its synonyms *malleable, meek, submissive, tractable* for one sense and *amenable, compliant, teachable* for another.  Also *[conformable](http://www.websters-dictionary-online.net/definitions/conformable)* may serve (as in cited example "I have been to you a true and humble wife, at all times to your will conformable") or *[menial](http://www.websters-dictionary-online.net/definitions/menial)* ("servile, slavish, subservient, obsequious or submissive").

For the tyrant, consider nouns *[dictator](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/dictator)*, *[director](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/director)*, *[taskmaster](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/taskmaster)* or *[taskmistress](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/taskmistress)*, or *[trainer](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/trainer)*.

Comment: +1 24 suggestions in an 81-word answer.  Are you trying to get in the Guinness Book of English Language and Usage Stack Exchange Site Records?

Comment: @Danielδ - No; anyway, it looks like the list in your comment to OP is denser with suggestions than my answer!

Answer (score 0):

I'd call that person ***obedient***

> submissive to the restraint or command of authority : willing to obey